# Sorting a stack using another stack

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I want to know the time complexity of this algorithm which is used to sort a stack using another stack. I thought it is O(N^2) but apparently it looks more than that.

```java
public static Stack<Integer> sort(Stack<Integer> s) {
    Stack<Integer> r = new Stack<Integer>();

    while(!s.isEmpty()) {
        int tmp = s.pop();
        while(!r.isEmpty() && r.peek() > tmp) {
            s.push(r.pop());
        }
        r.push(tmp);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Try to figure out an input (content of s) which will be the worst case scenario for this algorithm

Comment: It looks like it should be O(n^2) to me, what makes you think it isn't?

Answer (score 3):

If sorting stack `[x_2, .., x_n]` (stack grows towards right) takes `t(n-1)` time, sorting stack `[x_1, .., x_n]` time will do the following

1. Sort substack `[x_2, .., x_n]` of `s`
2. Pop `x_1` to `tmp`
3. Transfer at most `n-1` elements from `r` to `s`
4. Push `x_1` to `r`
5. Once again process the elements transfered in step 3., but they are in such order that inner while loop while never run.

So running the algorithm on `[x_1, .., x_n]` will take at most `t(n-1) + O(n)` time. That leads to (for some constant `c`)

```
t(n) <= O(n) + t(n-1) <= c * n + t(n-1)
t(n) <= c * n + c * (n - 1) + t(n-2) <= ... <= c * (1 + 2 + ... + n)
t(n) <= c * n(n + 1) / 2
```

So `t(n)` is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: In addition, OP's algorithm is essentially an implementation of [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Answer (score 0):

Looks O(n^2) to me. I'm guessing that an already-sorted stack has the worst-case performance. I counted the number of times that `s.push` gets executed, given an already-sorted stack of a particular size.

```
Stack of size 1. backpushes: 0
Stack of size 2. backpushes: 1
Stack of size 3. backpushes: 3
Stack of size 4. backpushes: 6
Stack of size 5. backpushes: 10
Stack of size 6. backpushes: 15
Stack of size 7. backpushes: 21
Stack of size 8. backpushes: 28
Stack of size 9. backpushes: 36
```

0,1,3,6,10 is the sequence of [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). A sorted stack of size N requires (N^2 + N)/2 backpushes. That makes it O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

*This problem can be done in o(n^2) complexity .This can be done without using popping the largest number and storing rest elements in second stack and updating the size of first stack,then pushing back to first stack.Have a look at the code snippet.*

```
   #include<stdio.h>
            func(struct stack *s1)
            {
                            struct stack* s2=(struct stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct stack))
                            int i=0;
                            int max=INT_MIN;
                            size=s1->size;
                            if(s1->size==0)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                            for(;i<size;i++)
                            {

                                while(size(s1)!=size)//popping the elements and pushing in s2 stack and keeping track of maximum element.
                                {

                                    temp=pop(s1);
                                    if(temp>max)
                                    {

                                        push(s2,max);
                                        max=temp;
                                    }

                                }
                                push(s1,max);//pushing the max element into stack s1 back and updating the size in push operation.
                                while(!empty(s2))//pushing extracted numbers back into stack s1 from s2.
                                {
                                    push(s1,pop(s2));

                                }

                            }


        }
```

Comment: While providing code is a great way to answer a question, it is best to provide some sort of explanation as to what the code is doing, what you did to resolve the issue, etc.